# Get message of Annotation java.validation.constraints.Size

Tags: validation, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I create a panel with JavaFx and springboot, I use Spring-data-jpa to do the CRUD with my DataBase MySql but I would want to check validations how max characters in a field and if I throw a error I would want to show a message dialog. When the program throws the exception it would shows the text that contain *'message' the variable 'name' in the @Entity Person*.

But when throw the issue doesn't enter in *catch (ConstraintViolationException e)*

I have used *DataAccessException* but not found this Exception neither

How to fix the problem? Is there a better solution?

**Entity Person**

```
   import lombok.Data;
   import javax.persistence.*;
   import javax.validation.constraints.Size;    

    @Data
    @Entity 
    public class Person { 
      @Id
      private Integer id;

      @Size(max = 20, message = "Max characters is 20")
      private String name;
    }
```

**ControllerPerson class**

```
import com.implica.entity.Person;
import com.implica.repository.IPersonRepository;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class DatosPersonalesController implements Initializable { 

        @Autowired
        private IPersonRepository personRepo;

        private TextField nameTf;

        Person p;
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

            p = new Person();

            nameTf.setText("Text more longer that your capacity");
            p.setName(nameTf.getText());
        }

        try {
                personRepo.save(p);
        }  catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getConstraintViolations().toArray(new ConstraintViolation[1])[0].getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking (looks more like a spring-related question to me), but if you are asking how to do validatioon on the TextField: use a Textformatter

Answer (score 0):

The validation probably happens on flush not on save. So your try-catch-block needs to be around the complete transaction.